# Flash - How come I do not receive a security warning to allow cross-site requests?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, xss

I am using the URLLoader class to send data to a script that sends an email with that data; the URLLoader is also used to receive the return data on the status of the request. This email script is located on another domain ([webscript.io](https://www.webscript.io/), in this case; they host scripts written in LUA that can perform various functions when called). I don't want to have to get them to host a crossdomain.xml file, but when I visit the page to use the Flash app, I don't even get a security warning. Is that not the default action when there is cross-domain scripting in a Flash application without a crossdomain.xml file?

For your reference, here is the application: http://www.canadadocks.ca/build-dock-app/

Answer (score 0):

The cross domain issues are specifically for data that your SWF is retrieving from other domains. So if you're sending data (via a HTTP POST/GET), then this is not a problem.

Also, unless you're using the debug player, you won't see the security exception that occurs.

There are also various things that will not trigger the exception: like downloading and displaying an image from another domain. However, if you then try to access the bitmap data of that image, you'll get the security exception (unless the crossdomain.xml permits it).

So it can depend on what you're retrieving and what you're doing w/the data you fetch.

If you're still curious, you should further explain what type of data you're retrieving and what you do with it. As usual, it's better to explain that with code than with words ;)